# How to upgrade Android Phonegap 2.7.0 to 2.8.1

Tags: android, cordova, upgrade, updates

In the past, upgrading phonegap consisted of creating a new project and copying various files. Now the instructions just say "Run bin/update with the project path listed in the Cordova Source directory." OK, how do I do this?

I've tried this:

```
cd /path/to/phonegap-2.8.1/lib/android/bin 
./update /path/to/MyProject
```

It gets this error

```
mkdir: /path/to/MyProject/cordova: File exists
An unexpected error occurred: mkdir "$PROJECT_PATH"/cordova exited with 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on Windows 7 and the update script did not work for me - so I did it manually the same way as it is recommended for 2.4.0 > 2.5.0 (which is the last known manual update description). It works.

Hope this helps. Link to update guide is [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20Android).

PS. I was updating from 2.5.0 to 2.8.1.

Comment: from 2.4>2,5, it says "Copy files from bin/templates/cordova..." I don't see this folder, but I copied the whole cordova folder over. Seems to work.

Comment: Seems like PhoneGap developers updated the guides for manual upgrading all the way up till 2.8.0, but then the update script starts again.